# Json key lookup with variable in Python

Tags: python, json

json1

```
[{'one.10': 'eno', 'three': 1, 'two': False},
{'one.21': 'eon', 'three': 2, 'two': True},
{'one.31': 'noe', 'three': 3, 'two': False}]
#{'one.x': 'oen', 'three': y, 'two': True}
```

With above as json1 file in this format, and with json2 heavily nested:

```
json2['Item']["21"]
```

A bit convoluted but can "21" be replaced by a variable? and if so could you have the variable set to x value of one.x in json1 by searching for the y value of "'three': y" ie search for 3 and get an x of 31?

```
json2['Item'][x] # for known y
```

Edit. json1 in reality is switched a bit:

```
[{"TextKey": "ItemName.x", "Name": "y", ...}
...]
```

json2 is like:

```
{
    "Item": {
        "10": {
            "djdj": True,
            ...
            "hduf": "dpdk"
        }

        "11": {
            "djdj": True,
            "info": {
            ...
            }
            ...
            "hduf": "dppk"
         }
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It might help people if you broke down the question more.  What are you actually trying to do?  You pretty much need to explain everything you wrote down more because no one is able to understand your question.

Comment: Seems like more than just a "bit" convoluted :p but, yes, it can all be done. I think. You want something like `json2['Item2'][extract_x_from_one_key (json1[index_of_three_value])`? Does the data "have" to be stores this way?

Comment: I get your question (partly tough), you want get the values from a json1 file. the 'x' value is the 'one.x' in the first column, the y value is the value in front of the "three" keyword??? You want to find the row based on "y" keyword and then use "x" from that row to use in >> json2["item"][x]??? am I correct???

Comment: @fazkan: What does is mean to say **the value in front of the "three" keyword** for data in a dictionary (which is unordered)?

Comment: Wasn't expecting a response that quick. anyway json1 and json2 are external files I can read them in and assign them to a variable fine. @fazkan the y would be "''three': y" or rather "'three': "y"". With the 'x' number being the identifier of a nest in json2. Data doesn't have to be stored this way but ideally I'd leave as be. I suppose the assigned variable could be manipulated if need be.

Comment: But yea @Terminus something like that command, currently I can't even get a variable to work in place of "21"

Comment: Do you have a sample `json2` you could post here?

Comment: json2 is heavily nested but its a 'proper' json if there is such a thing so the ['Item']["21"] is outputting the right nest from it, json1 I can't do the same with as the nests aren't externally identified (its a dict or array of some kind right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to search by a property of items in json1 to get keys for items in json2.

**Script**

```
json1 = [
    {"TextKey": "ItemName.09", "ID" : 0},
    {"TextKey": "ItemName.18", "ID" : 1},
    {"TextKey": "ItemName.27", "ID" : 2},
    {"TextKey": "ItemName.36", "ID" : 3},
    {"TextKey": "ItemName.45", "ID" : 4},
    {"TextKey": "ItemName.54", "ID" : 5}
]

json2 = {
    "Item": {
        "09": { "data": "a" },
        "18": { "data": "b" },
        "27": { "data": "c" },
        "36": { "data": "d" },
        "45": { "data": "e" },
        "54": { "data": "f" }
    }
}

json1SearchValues = [4,2,9]

for searchVal in json1SearchValues:
    # Use list comprehension to search json1 on property ID by searchVal 
    json1Item = [j1 for j1 in json1 if j1["ID"] == searchVal]
    # Assuming ID is unique, expecting one match
    if len(json1Item) == 1:
        json2ItemKey = json1Item[0]["TextKey"].split(".")[1]
        print "Found (json1 ID = " + str(searchVal) + ") -> (json2 Key = " + json2ItemKey + ") -> " + str(json2["Item"][json2ItemKey])
    # If there is no or more than one json1 item with that ID, do something else
    else:
        print "Invalid Key (" + str(searchVal) + ")"
```

**Output**

```
Found (json1 ID = 4) -> (json2 Key = 45) -> {'data': 'e'}
Found (json1 ID = 2) -> (json2 Key = 27) -> {'data': 'c'}
Invalid Key (9)
```

Comment: I'm getting invalid syntax on the print lines need to () it. ie: print("Invalid Key (" + str(searchVal) + ")"), just need to check I'm getting what I'm after with the imported jsons

Comment: Had to play with the numbers a bit as its not strictly unique, but that's done it. Much appreciated, I had tried j1 for j1 ... previously but was getting nowhere myself. Next I need to flip and get a key from json2 for json1, but should be trivial enough now